# Using firebase functions to trigger an app engine process

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm implementing a firebase function in my app to trigger an action when a user uploads a video file into storage. Once the file is uploaded into storage, I want to send that file to App Engine to encode it and generate thumbnails. Is it possible to access app engine from Firebase Functions and then have app engine download the file from the storage url?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.encodeVideo = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
    const bucket = object.bucket;
    const path = object.name;
    const fileType = oject.contentType;

    //Access app engine and send file url/path to start the encoding
});
```

Once it is sent to app engine, the above function will be completed. I plan on putting it in a separate bucket and updating a firestore document in app engine (if possible).

Comment: You don't need App Engine for this. With a Cloud Function triggered by Cloud Storage is good enough but the short answer is yes and I agree with Frank

Comment: I believe app engine is needed (or another similar product) based on what I read since firebase functions have a limit on what goes through them in terms of processing/memory intensive like encoding video content

Comment: That’s true, but please keep in mind that the processing capacity will vary depending on the [memmory provisioned](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#compute_time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably quite a few ways to do this, many of them not specific to Cloud Functions.

For example if you implement you functionality as a [Cloud Endpoint on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine), you can perform a HTTP call (like `fetch()`) to it from Cloud Functions.

This also seems to be possible without Cloud Endpoints, by using a [regular HTTP(S) endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/communicating-between-services) for your App Engine service.